# Is it possible to create a custom distribution of OpenOffice, or a way to package it into my java application?

Tags: openoffice.org, software-distribution

I've got simple java-based ppt->swf sub-project that basically works.  The open source software out there, [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) and [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) do the job great.

The thing is, to do this I need to install OO.o and run it in server mode.  And to do that I have to install OO.o, which is *allot* of software (~160MB) just to convert the source PPT files to an intermediate format.  Also, the public OO.o distributions are platform specific and I'd really like a single, cross platform set of files.  And, I'd like to not interfer with a system's current settings, like file extension associations.

As things are now, my project is not particularly 'software distribution friendly'.

So, the questions are:

- Is it possible to create a custom distribution of OpenOffice?  How would one about this?
- How lightweight and unobtrusive can I make the installation?
- Would it be possible to have a truly cross platform distribution since there would be no OO.o UI?
- Are there any licensing issues I need to be aware of?  (On my list of things to check out, but if you them already then TIA!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not unless you are neck deep coding in the OpenOffice project.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea to accomplish such task, but Microsoft has its [PPT viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=048dc840-14e1-467d-8dca-19d2a8fd7485&displaylang=en) that is for free and very small, maybe in .NET (C#) you can use some kinda function to save into a intermediate file that you need...

and by the way, how are you handling slide transictions?

I found a [software](http://www.justdosoft.com/powerpoint-to-flash/) that does that but you need MS PPT installed.

this was just an idea, **now regarding your actually question:**

you can create your own installation of OO, just [jump to the Installation project](http://installation.openoffice.org/) and follow the lines.

*I did not read 'til the end, but from the 1st paragraph it seams what you are searching for.*

Comment: MS PPT viewer: no go for my project--not cross platform.  Also, JODConverter works directly with OO.o to take the PPT to SWF.  I don't want to lose that.

Comment: I've seen the the OO.o installation project documentation you linked to, but it is very 'sparse'--I get nothing out of it.  Also seems Solaris-oriented.  (I'm developing on a Mac).  But thanks anyways.